# error: 'strstr' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi2, strstr

i am writing a application on raspberry pi with shared memory. I am using the function strstr() in my self written shared memory library. When i compile the library on OS X with clang++ i get no error. If i compile it on my raspberry pi i get the error: 'strstr' was not declared in this scope.

I tried to update my raspberry but with no success, can you give me any hint or solution what to do.

Header-Datei

```
#ifndef SHAREDMEMORY_H
#define SHAREDMEMORY_H

#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_SERVICES 99

/**
 * Datei mit der Datenbank.
 */
#define FILEPATH "database.dat"
/**
 * Anzahl der Zeichen in der
 * Datenbank.
 */
#define CHARACTERS 2500
/**
 * Größe der Datenbank.
 */
#define FILESIZE (CHARACTERS*sizeof(char))

class SharedMemory {
public:
    /**
     * Constructor 
     */
    SharedMemory();
    /**
     * Desctructor
     */
    ~SharedMemory();
    /**
     * Method to open file
     * @param string: Path to file, has to exist
     * @param int: for reading 0 
     *             for writing 1
     * @return bool: true on success
     *               false on error
     */
    bool openFile( std::string, int );
    /**
     * Method to map file to memory
     * @param string: Path to file, has to exist
     * @param int: for reading 0 
     *             for writing 1
     * @return bool: true on success
     *               false on error
     */
    bool mappingFile( int );
    /**
     * Method to remove file from memory
     * @return bool: true on success
     *               false on error
     */
    bool unmapFile();
    /**
     * Method to write information to file
     * @param string: data to write
     * e.g. string="#1:127.0.0.1:8000", #number range 0-99.
     * @return bool: true on success
     *               false on error
     */
    bool set( std::string );
    /**
     * Method to read information from file
     * @param string: need to cointains id, if success
     *                then contains info from id.
     *  e.g. string="1", number range "0"-"99".
     * @return bool: true on success
     *               false on error
     */
    bool get( std::string& );
private:
    /**
     * Datei-Deskriptor.
     */
    int fd;
    /**
     * Zeiger auf Dateiinhalt.
     */
    char *mapPointer;
    /**
     * Path to file
     */
    std::string filePath;
};


#endif /* SHAREDMEMORY_H */
```

Cpp-Datei

```
#include "SharedMemory.h"

SharedMemory::SharedMemory() { }

SharedMemory::~SharedMemory() { }

bool SharedMemory::openFile( std::string _path, int mode ) {
    if ( mode ) {
        fd = open( _path.c_str(), O_RDWR, (mode_t)0600 );
    } else {
        fd = open( _path.c_str(), O_RDONLY, (mode_t)0600 );
    }
    if ( fd == -1 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool SharedMemory::mappingFile( int mode ){
    void* tmpPointer;
    if ( mode ) {
        tmpPointer = mmap( 0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    } else {
        tmpPointer = mmap( 0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    }

    if( tmpPointer == MAP_FAILED ) {
        close( fd );
        return false;
    } 
    mapPointer = (char*) tmpPointer;

    return true;
}

bool SharedMemory::unmapFile() {
    int ret = munmap(mapPointer, FILESIZE);
    close( fd );
    if ( ret == -1 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool SharedMemory::set( std::string s ) {
    /**
     * Filter id, find the id in the file.
     * If Values exist and id is valid, insert value
     * -> if value not exists, insert "No_Service".
     * if given id is invalid, return false
     */
    int mid = s.find( ";" );
    int begin = s.find( "#" );
    std::string id = s.substr( begin + 1, mid - begin);
    std::string info = s.substr( mid + 1, s.length() );
    if ( info == "" ) {
        info = "No_Service";
    }
    char* i = strstr( mapPointer, id.c_str() );
    while ( *i++ != ';' );
    for ( auto x: info ) {
        *i++ = x;
    }
    for ( int j = 0; j < ( 20 - info.length() ); ++j ) {
        *i++ = ' ';
    }

    return true;
}

bool SharedMemory::get( std::string& id ){
    /**
     * Filter id, find the id in the file.
     * save data in string s.
     */
    int tmp;
    try {
        tmp = stoi( id );
    } catch ( ... ) {
        id = "No_Service";
        return false;
    }

    if ( tmp > 100 || tmp < 1 ){
        id = "No_Service";
        return false;
    } 

    id += ";";
    char* i = strstr( mapPointer, id.c_str() );
    while ( *i++ != ';' );
    id = "";
    do {
        id += *i++;
    } while( *i != ' ' && *i != ';' );

    if ( id == "No_Service" ){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should at least thank us preemptively for helping or insert a smiley face to set the mood. You sound rude asking us things with a straight face.

Comment: when i write something like hey everyone or it gets instantly deleted. I am new to stack overflow and not sure why this happens. Tried to edit it multiple times. can you tell me why it has this behavior xD? and some admin deleted my endphrase where i was thanking everyone for there help -.-

Comment: Not familiar with raspberry pie, but try `include <cstring>`?

Comment: @gurghet, you're not supposed to have 'thanks' and smiley faces etc. on stackoverflow. It's a question and answer site, not a forum.

Comment: @crobar welcome to the Internet where you interact with real people, not machines (yet)

Comment: @gurghet, sorry, I should have been clear, it's [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) on stackoverflow not to include greeting and other things. You might think you are being nice, but actually you are hindering people by wasting their time with useless fluff.

Comment: You may think you are hindering people with useless stuff but it's been proven that working in a welcoming environment lower corthisol levels and enhance focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try including `cstring` (and calling `std::strstr`) or including `string.h`.

This is specified in the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr